# Where can I find legal acts (USA) for storing or processing social security number, tax id, driver license?

Tags: legal, storage, social-security-number

There is a PCI DSS for credit card processing. Does somewhere exist similar requirements for personal data processing, especially in US?

Comment: I Googled "US PII laws": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information#United_States and https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/6-502-0467?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true&bhcp=1